# Unable to get Apache NiFi rest API working

Tags: apache-nifi

I am following [this](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html) regarding Apache NiFi rest API.

I have a nifi instance running locally on minikube, and I can access its UI at host:port/nifi

When I try to access its rest API, say:

host:port/controller/cluster

It just directs me to NiFi UI.

What am I missing?

PS: Got it. I need to have it as:

> host:port/nifi-api/....